# Sharing a Windows mapped drive over a seperate network

Tags: windows, networking, network-shares, file-sharing

I'm trying to set up a way to share over my local network another shared network drive folder.

My server is in the middle of 2 networks (2 NICs) and can get network shares from "X" network but my local network "Z" can't access them, so I want my server to bridge a few folders from X to Z.

My attempted solution is to map the shares from X network then Windows File Share it to the Z network. The issue is Windows won't allow this.
My 2nd attempt is to create a shortcut to either the network path, or to the mapped network drive and then Windows File Share it, again there is no option like there would be for a normal folder.
I also tried to use `subst` to map the shortcut, mapped drive or direct path with no luck.

Comment: You have to provide more information.  The only way this would be possible is if a route can be made to the respective network. If these are two logically separate intranet networks that’s impossible

Comment: Why not subnet X and Z together? There probably is a windows kludge to do what you want without that...but...uck

Comment: @mitts Not sure what you mean by subnetting them together?